# Convert simple string into array

Tags: zapier

I'm wanting to use the Code by Zapier action to convert a string like this: "product 1, product 2, product 3" into an array like this [product 1, product 2, product 3] so the subsequent Zapier actions will run for as many times as there are values in the array. What code do I need to enable this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! This is not code writing service, we do not tend to answer questions that do not show any research done. Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method to achieve that:

```
>>> products_str = "product 1, product 2, product 3"
>>> products = products_str.split(', ')
>>> products
['product 1', 'product 2', 'product 3']
```